# chrome webRequest.onAuthListener leads to website hanging

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, webrequest

I'm setting proxies in chrome with this function

```js
const setProxy = (proxy) => {
    const config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
            singleProxy: {
                scheme: proxy.protocol.toLowerCase(),
                host: proxy.ip,
                port: parseInt(proxy.port)
            },
            bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };
    chrome.proxy.settings.set({ value: config, scope: "regular" }, () => { });
}
```

and I'm trying to autenticate proxies setting a listener to the onAuthRequired event as I show below.

```js
const authListener = async (details) => {
    console.log("Auth url", details.url);
    let credentials = await getObjectFromLocalStorage("active");
    if(credentials===undefined){
    return;
    }  
    let {username, password} = credentials;
    console.log("CREDENTIALS :", username, " ", password);
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
  authListener,
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] },
  ["asyncBlocking"]
);
```

Once I activate the proxy and I try to load any website chrome just keeps loading and does nothing. As you can see there are some console.log() which work fine and produce expected values.

I tried both "asyncBlocking" and "blocking" and I still get the same issue. I'm also adding the listener in a service_worker